# Kivy changing texture of image gives black image

Tags: python, kivy

Kivy after changing Image.texture, gives black result.

My code:

```
self.ids['profimage'].source = './add_photo.png'
```

Few lines later...

```
pimg = Image.open(bio).convert('RGB') # bio is a valid _io.BytesIO object with image data
pimg = pimg.crop((0, 0, int(self.width*0.3), int(self.width*0.3)))
pimg.save(data, format='png')
data.seek(0)
im = CoreImage(BytesIO(data.read()), ext='png')
self.ids['profimage'].texture = im.texture
```

[image: Before]

Before changing texture ^

[image: After]

After changing texture ^

Could anybody help me with that?